# Can a 35K BTU home wok burner improve food taste, and deliver restaurant wok hei?

Tags: wok

Many Cantonese restaurant chefs advise me to install a [wok burner](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/112617), ***even in my home***, to procure [wok hei 鑊氣](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/5157).  But  ["commercial wok burners blazes at over 100,000 BTU/hr!"](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6010/how-can-i-make-chinese-fried-rice-like-they-do-on-the-east-coast#comment129096_19960)  ["[A] wok burner can deliver up to [...] 200,000 BTU/h of thermal power."](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/62363)

##### But are these chefs wrong? Because [*HOME* wok burners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtBvXJIXZfE) discharge merely [≤ 35K BTU](https://www.subzero-wolf.com/wolf/cooktops-and-rangetops/range-top/48-inch-sealed-burner-rangetop-4-burners-wok), too little to be a ["professional wok burner (which would likely require expensive ventilation upgrades for use indoors)"](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/13816)!

##### What can a [≤ 35K BTU  wok burner](https://youtu.be/9YtKjarWzz4) accomplish, that a gas burner or electric induction cooktop can't ?  What's exclusive to a ≤ 35K BTU wok burner  ?

[image]

[image]